# Position 2 texts same height

Tags: html, css, alignment

Trying to position "Certamente não" and "Certamente Sim" at the same height.

Using margin top doesn't seem to align them correctly.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried absolute positioning?

Comment: Add HTML & Code here

Comment: Please do not provide images of text, please provide the CSS as text in the question, properly formatted. Please provide more CSS, enough to reproduce your problem, preferably as a snippet (Ctrl + M).

Comment: Please don't capitalise classnames, instead of using CamelCase hyphenate as per convention. .CertamenteSim --> .certamente-sim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "flexbox" to align them. For example:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

<div class="parent">
  <span>Certamente não</span>
  <span>Certamente Sim</span>
</div>
```

Learn more about flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Same for the dots you have there. Put them all inside the parent container with display:flex